# How to get values for time intervals of hours in one day in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, rdfs

I have a simple RDF Graph with the following form

```
v:order1 v:time   "2016-01-18T04:00:01.536"^^xsd:dateTime .                                  
v:order1 v:value  "3118915.75"^^xsd:string .
...
v:orderN v:time   "2016-01-18T04:59:58.536"^^xsd:dateTime .                                  
v:orderN v:value  "4117779.00"^^xsd:string .
```

The graph records values for specific timestamps; therefore, a lot of data is generated in one day.
I need to obtain the difference in the time interval of one hour, from the last `v:orderN` and the first `v:Order1` value of each hour for a SPARQL 1.1. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking.   What do you mean by "RDF dataset with the following form"?  An RDF graph is a bunch of triples.  What you've shown looks more like a row of a table with two columns,  It's not clear what you mean by " the difference from the last and the first value of each hour"  What's the "last value of an hour"?  What's the "first value of an hour"?   Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  With the data you've shown us, what's the actual value you're trying to get?

Comment: Just to clarify, for each hour per day, you want to have the difference between the max and the min value of all values in that hour?

Comment: When an hour starts it records a value. The same when the value ends. I need the difference of those values, not the max and min values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example that we can work with always helps a lot.  In the future, please provide data that we can run queries against, and let us know what the desired outcomes are.  Since you didn't specify otherwise, I'm going to assume that the dataset only looks at dates within a one day range, so that we can group these just based on the hour, and we don't have to worry about the particular date.  Here's some data where in the hour 04, there's a change from 10 to 12 (so the difference is 2), and in the hour 05, there's a change from 40 to 50 (so the difference is 10).  Also note that I'm using xsd:decimal values, since talking about the difference of strings doesn't really make sense.

```
@prefix v: <urn:ex:> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

v:order1 v:time   "2016-01-18T04:00:01.536"^^xsd:dateTime .                                  
v:order1 v:value  "10.0"^^xsd:decimal .

v:order2 v:time   "2016-01-18T04:32:58.536"^^xsd:dateTime .                                  
v:order2 v:value  "11.00"^^xsd:decimal .

v:order3 v:time   "2016-01-18T04:59:58.536"^^xsd:dateTime .                                  
v:order3 v:value  "12.00"^^xsd:decimal .

v:order4 v:time   "2016-01-18T05:00:01.536"^^xsd:dateTime .                                  
v:order4 v:value  "40.00"^^xsd:decimal .

v:order5 v:time   "2016-01-18T05:59:58.536"^^xsd:dateTime .                                  
v:order5 v:value  "50.00"^^xsd:decimal .prefix v: <urn:ex:>
```

The query is pretty straightforward.  To find the latest value in an hour, you just find the entry for which there's no later value in the same hour.  Similarly for the earliest value in an hour.  Then you just compute the difference.

```sql
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?hour (?latest - ?earliest as ?difference) {

  { select (hours(?time) as ?hour) ?earliest {
      ?order v:time ?time ; v:value ?earliest 
      filter not exists {
        ?order_ v:time ?time_
        filter (hours(?time_) = hours(?time) && ?time_ < ?time)
      }
    }
  }

  { select (hours(?time) as ?hour) ?latest {
      ?order v:time ?time ; v:value ?latest 
      filter not exists {
        ?order_ v:time ?time_
        filter (hours(?time_) = hours(?time) && ?time < ?time_)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
---------------------
| hour | difference |
=====================
| 04   | 2.00       |
| 05   | 10.00      |
---------------------
```